# Should i use state for static/inmutable data in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I have to calculate something to use it in my component and I want to know if I should calculate it in my initial state or just calculate it outside my state

**example of the calculation done within my state**

```js
constructor(props: UserProfileProps) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    id: this.props.route.params.id
    userData: usersData.find((user) => user.id === this.state.id);
  };
}
```

**example of the calculation done outside my state**

```js
constructor(props: UserProfileProps) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    id: this.props.route.params.id
  };
}

userData = usersData.find((user) => user.id === this.state.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Class component:

```
 constructor(props: UserProfileProps) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    id: this.props.route.params.id
    userData: {} 
  };
 }

 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const {route} = this.props
    if (route.params.id !== prevProps.route.params.id) {
        const userData = UsersData.find((user) => user.id === route.params.id
        this.setState(userDate)
     }
  }
```

Functional component:
If it's a heavy calculation you should use the useMemo hook.

```
const userData = (useMemo() => {
   return UsersData.find((user) => user.id === id); }, [id])
```

Comment: Can i use this hook in a class component or just in functional components?

Comment: no @Lucas you can not use react hooks in class components.